# cron job is not working in cpanel for subdomain?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel, cron-task

I am trying to run cron job on cpanel and my project is in laravel ... I have hosted that project on subdomain when I try to add path but it is not working.

```
usr/local/bin/ea-php81 /home/abc/public_html/crm.abc.in/ artisan notifications:send
```

and i checked the logs it throws **command not found error**

Comment: Try removing the space `/ artisan` and execute `usr/local/bin/ea-php81 /home/abc/public_html/crm.abc.in/artisan notifications:send`

Comment: @linktoahref no sir . not working...[2023-06-23 12:25:01] local.ERROR: Command "notifications:send" is not defined.